# Inserting sorted data to table with clustered index

Tags: sql-server-2005

An application is inserting sorted data row by row into a table and I want to improve the performance of the insertion.

Should I make a clustered index before I run the app (it is empty at the beginning) or at the end of the running?

Maybe it's better to import the data to a temporary table and insert it to the main table every X insertions?

Comment: Just so you're aware - a clustered index says *nothing* about the order that you'll obtain rows back from the table at a later date.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using (update question tag)? What is the source of the data? Excel, CSV? Look in to using the import facilities of SQL Server rather than writing your own app.

Comment: The source is calculations made by an application that insert each result in a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise removing and adding indexes when you need to do an import.

You commented that

> The source is calculations made by an application that insert each
>   result in a separate query

Which means you cannot get around the individual insert statements. So the next solution to consider is multi-threading your application.

Let the database handle the sorting of the data via the index, it will be the IO latency between your application and the database causing delays.

If you can be calculating the next result while another thread is waiting for it's `insert` to complete you will save a lot of time.

**Alternative solution**

You could let the application write it's results to a file (quick) and then bulk import the results to the database using SSIS or BULK INSERT.

Comment: I'll try the second approach. Thanks.